# How to test if a folder is there, then using that information to go somewhere

Tags: batch-file

Here is my wip program

```
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 0B


:JRNLMENU
CLS
ECHO WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO DO?
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO 1-CREATE NEW ENTRY
ECHO 2-READ OLD ENTRIES
ECHO 3-EXIT
SET/P "CHO=>"
IF %CHO%==1 GOTO TESTFOR
IF %CHO%==2 GOTO VIEWENTRY
IF %CHO%==3 GOTO EXIT
ECHO ERROR, PLEASE TRY AGAIN
PAUSE
CLS
GOTO JRNLMENU


:TESTFOR
CLS
CD C:\USERS\%USERNAME%\DOCUMENTS\
IF EXIST CATSYSTEMS GOTO CREATEJRNL
IF NOT EXIST CATSYSTEMS GOTO CREATEFLDR


:CREATEFLDR
MD c:\USERS\%USERNAME%\DOCUMENTS\CATSYSTEMS
CLS
ECHO HELLO
PAUSE
CLS
GOTO CREATEJRNL


:CREATEJRNL
ECHO TYPE WHAT YOU WOULD LIKE TO PUT IN YOUR JOURNAL
ECHO PRESS ENTER TO GO TO THE NEXT LINE
PAUSE
```

I cant get it to skip createfldr if the folder is there. It will create it in the right place but it doesnt seem to check if it is there. I have a batch file that locks the folder (as most people have seen) so I think the testfor section should work. Most of the other code I use often though so I am pretty sure all the commands work. Any help would be great :)

Comment: Have you tried using the full path `IF EXIST c:\USERS\%USERNAME%\DOCUMENTS\CATSYSTEMS` like in the `MD` statement?

Comment: Just did and it didnt seem to change.

Comment: This is working as is on my computer - Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Is it popping up the hello? I put that there to see if it was going to the create folder part.

Comment: It only popped up hello the first time I ran it. Then it created the folder, when I run it again, it skips hello correctly.

Comment: Any idea why it wouldn't work on a windows 7 computer?

Comment: I have one of those - I'll try it over there. - LOL! It works there too.

Comment: Add the `/d` option to the `CD` command.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try. it Must just be my computer. Oh well :) thanks for all the help so far everybody :)

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, I didnt have it test for the folder in the right place, Halfbit, you were right. Just when I typed it in I forgot the \documents and that was kind of important. Thanks for all the help and advice :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use following version of your batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 0B


:JRNLMENU
CLS
ECHO WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO DO?
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO 1-CREATE NEW ENTRY
ECHO 2-READ OLD ENTRIES
ECHO 3-EXIT
SET /P "CHO=>"
IF %CHO%==1 GOTO TESTFOR
IF %CHO%==2 GOTO VIEWENTRY
IF %CHO%==3 GOTO EXIT
ECHO ERROR, PLEASE TRY AGAIN
PAUSE
GOTO JRNLMENU


:TESTFOR
CLS
CD /D "C:\USERS\%USERNAME%\DOCUMENTS\"
IF EXIST CATSYSTEMS GOTO CREATEJRNL
IF NOT EXIST CATSYSTEMS GOTO CREATEFLDR


:CREATEFLDR
MD "C:\USERS\%USERNAME%\DOCUMENTS\CATSYSTEMS"
CLS
ECHO HELLO
PAUSE
CLS
GOTO CREATEJRNL


:CREATEJRNL
ECHO TYPE WHAT YOU WOULD LIKE TO PUT IN YOUR JOURNAL
ECHO PRESS ENTER TO GO TO THE NEXT LINE
PAUSE
```

There are some small corrections. The perhaps important ones are:

1. Command `CD` without optional parameter `/D`  could fail if the current working directory is not on drive `C:`. Therefore it is always better to use `/D` on changing current working directory if no control on which directory is the working directory (`Start In` in shortcut properties) on execution of the batch file.
2. A user account name can include also a space character, see Microsoft article [Creating User and Group Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726984.aspx). Therefore it is advisable to include all paths containing `%USERNAME%` in double quotes.

Two more hints:

1. Better would be perhaps also to use `%USERPROFILE%` instead of `C:\USERS\%USERNAME%` if not all users use Windows Vista and later Windows versions or the user account directory is not on drive `C:`.
2. Run your batch file with `@ECHO ON` at top instead of `@ECHO OFF` to see what is going on when executing the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

To test for folders on a local filesystem reliably, you need a trailing backslash:

```
IF EXIST CATSYSTEMS\ GOTO CREATEJRNL
IF NOT EXIST CATSYSTEMS\ GOTO CREATEFLDR
```

Using double quotes allows you to use short or long names:

```
IF EXIST "CATSYSTEMS\" GOTO CREATEJRNL
IF NOT EXIST "CATSYSTEMS\" GOTO CREATEFLDR
```